# testing replication from Citus to my RDS Aurora Postgres on subscriber no data is coming

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, replication, amazon-aurora, citus

I am testing replication from Citus(Cloud Hosted) to my RDS Aurora Postgres with ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Replication.Logical.html#AuroraPostgreSQL.Replication.Logical.Configure

Everything ran successful but on subscribers, no data is coming so what may be wrong? how do I troubleshoot

> SELECT count(*) FROM LogicalReplicationTest;

Note: on Citus DB I can See Publication:
[image]

But in my RDS can't see Subscriptions in the list in spite of CREATE SUBSCRIPTION testsub CONNECTION was successful:
[image]

I observed that when I run `SELECT count(*) FROM LogicalReplicationTest;` there is no data but only column name showing Lock symbol as shown in this screenshot! any idea what this lock symbol means apart from the Read-only Column? why it's not listing data inside that table which is in publisher DB Is there any permission I have to delegate to the table when creating a publication?

[image]

Comment: What does "on citus" mean?  Your self-hosted PostgreSQL with that extension installed?  Citus cloud?

Comment: What versions of everything?  What is in the error log on the Aurora?  Rather than giving us screenshots from PgAdmin, show us text from psql.  Debugging one thing at a time is already enough work, you don't need to debug PgAdmin simultaneously as well.

Comment: @jjanes we are using Citus cloud service

Comment: @jjanes Actually there were no errors while creating subscriptions ie CREATE SUBSCRIPTION Query returned successfully in 2 min 13 secs. so subscription is created successfully with no errors but when check table don't see injected data in replica side so I want to know how to troubleshoot this issue

Comment: also when I ran SELECT count(*) FROM LogicalReplicationTest; there is no error in RDS logs but the table content are blank .....I have updated this in my question

Comment: Version for RDS aurora-postgresql13 and that of Postgres hosted in Citus DB is lesser or not the same so can that be the reason for not showing replication table data or subscriptions?

Comment: My Citus DB Postgres version is 9.51

Comment: @jjanes
Ohh my mistake Citus DB Postgres Version is 13.2 and Citus Version is 9.5-1 and Version for RDS aurora-postgresql13. So this seems may not be a version issue.